# Oscillation of charged particle inside charged torus

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge, oscillators

At our university we were given this problem: charged ball with mass of $m = 0.0001 kg$ and charge $Q = -10^{-5} C$ is placed on geometric axis of thin torus with inner radius of $r_{inner} = 0.05 m$, outer radius of $r_{outer} = 0.1 m$ and surface charge density $\sigma = 10^{-5} C$. Compute oscillation time for small deviation, this is when we only slightly flick the ball from stable state.

First, I took a look at this [article](http://web.csulb.edu/~htahsiri/studyguide/Mathphysics%20560A/Drop%20electron%20Proj.pdf) and a PDF [presentation](http://www.phys.uri.edu/gerhard/PHY204/tsl34.pdf).

**The attempt at a solution:** I think it's worth mentioning that $$Q_{tor} = \sigma A = \sigma \pi (r_{outer}^2 - r_{inner}^2) \approx 2.356 \cdot 10^{-7} C$$

Next ,using the equation for electric field of a charged ring

$$ E_z = \frac{Qz}{4 \pi \varepsilon_0 (r^2 + z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}} $$

I tried obtaining formula for electric field of torus (wider ring) by integration of infinitesimal rings from inner to outer radius. Using Symbolab I managed to obtain following equation

$$ E_{torus} = \frac{Qz}{4 \pi \varepsilon_0} (\frac{r}{z^3 \sqrt{\frac{r^2}{z^2}+1}})_{r_{inner}} ^ {r_{outer}} $$.

Since distance $z$ is almost zero *and unknown*, this equation becomes useless (I think?). From here on, I'm lost. Can somebody please help me move forward?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: 8.36*10^(-3) seconds

Comment: "A thin torus" do we assume a disc with a hole in the middle?

Comment: If we do take it as a disc like structure, then the question is pretty straight forward

Comment: A thin torus... Yes, it can be viewed as a disk with a hole in a middle.

Comment: Does your torus have a single surface, or two (top and bottom)? Your expression for $Q$ suggests it is charged on one surface only. Your expression for the $E_z$ is obviously wrong, as it explodes at $z=0$. I suggest you try to find the slope of the E field with z - for small displacements you expect it to be linear, otherwise you cannot calculate the frequency (you need to end up with something that looks like the equation of motion for SHO).